# How do I "dress in layers" when I need to stay business casual indoors?

Tags: dress-code

Winter time is coming soon, and that means having to wear a lot of sweaters outdoors.

At the workplace, I can usually get away with a nice sweater without any patterns on it, thanks to being in a programming field with little client contact.  But I am still expected to keep a business-casual level of attire.

The problem is, the office kicks up the heat throughout the building during the winter, and it can get unreasonably warm - at which point I need to remove my sweater.

Most of the time for warmer weather I wear a polo shirt for business-casual, but these all have collars and buttons that bump up against a sweater, so I can't just wear one underneath.

What other options do I have to wear under a sweater that would still keep the same business-casual level of professionalism as a polo shirt?  Preferably, I'd also like to avoid having to switch shirts in the middle of a work day.

Comment: what do you mean "buttons that bump up against a sweater"

Comment: How about a short sleeved cotton shirt (rather than a polo shirt) that you can wear with a sweater over and then take it off as needed?

Comment: How do your coworkers handle this situation?

Comment: Or a v neck sweater

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wear polo shirts and cotton shirts under a jumper/ sweater without any problems with the buttons or collars.

[image: mannequins wearing collared shirts under jumpers/sweaters]

You just need to make sure your jumper has a wide enough neck to accommodate the shirt collar. V-neck style jumpers are also good, especially if you're wearing a tie underneath, but as you can see in the image, round necks shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I think this is my problem - sweaters that have a tall collar won't work with polo shirts, so I need sweaters with a wider neck.  Thank you.

Comment: @Zibbobz "v neck sweater" is the keyword here then

Comment: I dress like this and when it's cold I put a blazer to help keep me warm. I left the blazer in the office (hanging in my chair) and use a heavy coat to comute from home to work and when I get to the office, I put the heavy coat in the chair and wear the blazer. Even just a polo shirt with the blazer is super cool and "smart business casual" at leas for where I work

Answer (score 10):

The general answer to that will be: ask your manager what is appropriate for your workplace culture. There is no strict definition of [business-casual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_casual).

Sometimes in winter I prefer set of 3 layers that looks like:

1. White t-shirt
2. Button-up shirt without a tie, probably something patterned as plain shirt is more formal
3. Blazer / sports coat

This set seems to be gender-neutral, at least in the US. Sweater can be replaced with a [fleece vest](https://www.vineyardvines.com/mens-outerwear/tech-fleece-harbor-vest/191620920363.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=&utm_content=GGL-Shopping-Vests&utm_campaign=VV%7CGGL%7CShopping%7CAlways%20On%7CMens%7CBlazers,%20Jackets%20and%20Vests%7CPLA&CID=ps%7Cgoogle%7Csem%7Cpla%7Cprosp%7Cmen%7Calways_on%7Cna%7Cnull%7Cna%7CVV%7CGGL%7CShopping%7CAlways%20On%7CMens%7CBlazers,%20Jackets%20and%20Vests%7CPLA%7CGGL-Shopping-Vests%7C191620920363%7Cpla&ds_rl=1272532&gclid=Cj0KCQjwoqDtBRD-ARIsAL4pviCT_CtMoshIG9gfrI8W2HAF_1jtAE3prASIEYkyEmbkylzv2duv5iUaAueHEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) (pretty [tech-y](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/katienotopoulos/i-wore-a-vest-like-jeff-bezos-for-a-week-to-see-if-id-be)) or a cardigan (pretty old-styley):

[image: Mr Rogers]

[image: Leslie Knope]

Answer (score 4):

The interwebs are full of style advice. [Here’s an article](https://ashleyweston.com/mens-wardrobe-essentials/wear-polo-shirt-sweater/) that recommends wearing an oxford or dress shirt under your sweater, or using a blazer over your polo, but not combining polos and sweaters. Personally, depending on the quality of the garments, I think you could get away with it sometimes.